# Removing Item from Collection / Changing field of Object

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

```
public void searchOwner(List<Appointments> appts, String owner) {
    Appointments theOne = null;
    for (Appointments temp : appts) {
        if (owner.equalsIgnoreCase(temp.owner.name)) {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            temp.setResolved(true);
        }
    }
}

public void checkRemoval() {
    for (Appointments appts : appointments) {
        if (appts.resolved == true) {
            appointments.remove(appts);
        }

//Iterator method used before enhanced for-loop
    public void checkRemovalI(){
    Iterator<Appointments> it = appointments.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        if(it.next().resolved = true){
            it.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

So far this is where I am encountering my problem. I am trying to check the arrayList of Appointments and see if the field (resolved) is set to true, however I am receiving an ConcurrentModification exception during the searchOwner method when trying to set resolved =  to true. I've tried using an Iterator in checkRemoval instead of an enhanced for-loop however that didn't help either. I really only need to get the part where the appointment is set to true to work, the checkRemoval seemed to be working early before implementing the changing of the boolean resolved. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can you post the code using iterator

Comment: i think your problem is not with the setting resolved = true but with the checkRemoval method. you cannot modify a list when you are looping it. either take a copy of the original list into some other list and work from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm willing to bet that the `ConcurrentModificationException` is not being caused where you say it is, but rather in `checkRemoval()`, which you're probably calling before the line you mention where you set `resolved` to true, hence your confusion.

I only say this because:

```
for (Appointments appts : appointments) {
    if (appts.resolved == true) {
        appointments.remove(appts);
    }
}
```

is a blatant concurrent modification. *You cannot remove elements from a collection while you are iterating through it in a loop.* Instead, you need to use an [iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
public void checkRemoval() {
    Iterator<Appointment> apptsIterator = appointments.iterator();
    while (apptsIterator.hasNext()){ 
        if (appts.next().resolved == true) 
            apptsIterator.remove(); //removes the last element you got via next()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment as well.. I was obviously trying to remove items from list while iterating through it. Problem solved, thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 1):

The ConcurrentModification exception is thrown, using the for loop, where the Collection gets modified. So the issue need not be the code that you haave posted. You might be having a loop over the appts List, which is calling this function.
Posting more of your code might help.

Comment: Ok, I see... Perfect I got it Working.. Switched back to the iterator method and changed location of where I called it and now it's working.. Thanks mucho !